# Header columns are breaking in PDF file using PHP and FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I am facing one issue while producing `PDF` file using `PHP and FPDF`. My code is below:

```
require_once('/var/www/hlwcab.com/public_html/cab/service/sms/smsAPIService.php');
class PDF extends FPDF{
    // Page header
    function Header(){
        // Logo
        $this->Image('../../../admin/img/HLW-CabManagementLogopdf.png',10,-1,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial','B',13);
        // Move to the right
        $this->Cell(80);
        // Title
        $this->Cell(80,10,'Report List',1,0,'C');
        // Line break
        $this->Ln(20);
    }
    // Page footer
    function Footer(){
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('Arial','I',8);
        // Page number
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Page '.$this->PageNo().'/{nb}',0,0,'C');
    }

}
if ($_REQUEST["action"]=="downloadMonthlyReportData") {
        $data=array();
        $start_time=$_POST['start_time'];
        $end_time=$_POST['end_time'];
        $sql="select * from cb_wallet_driver_logs order by id desc";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        if ($stmt->execute()) {
            $row = $stmt->fetchAll();
            $number_of_rows= count($row);
            if ($number_of_rows > 0) {
                $slno=1;
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $last_update=$value['last_update'];
                    $owner_id=$value['owner_id'];
                    $sql="select * from cb_owner_info where owner_id=:owner_id";
                    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':owner_id', htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($owner_id)));
                    if ($stmt->execute()) {
                        $orow = $stmt->fetchAll();
                        $number_of_orows= count($orow);
                        if ($number_of_orows > 0) {
                            foreach ($orow as $key => $val) {
                                $owner_name=$val['name'];
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    $dt = new DateTime($last_update);
                    $odate=$dt->format('d-m-Y');
                    $ndate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($odate));
                    $stdate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($start_time));
                    $endate=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($end_time));
                    if ($ndate >= $stdate && $ndate <= $endate) {
                        $data[]=array("sl_no"=>$slno,"owner_name"=>$owner_name,"last_update"=>$last_update,"book_id"=>$value['book_id'],"operator_total"=>$value['operator_total'],"ride_total"=>$value['ride_total']);
                        $slno++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        $result1=array();
        if (count($data) > 0) {
            $pdf = new PDF();
            //$pdf = new FPDF(); 
            //header
            $pdf->AddPage();
            $width_cell=array(10,30,40,40,30,30);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
            $pdf->SetFillColor(193,229,252);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],10,'Sl No',1,0,C,true);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],10,'Owner Name',1,0,C,true);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],10,'Date',1,0,C,true);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],10,'Booking ID',1,0,C,true);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,'Operator',1,1,C,true);
            $pdf->Cell($width_cell[5],10,'Ride',1,1,C,true);
            $pdf->SetFont('Arial','',10);
            //Background color of header//
            $pdf->SetFillColor(235,236,236); 
            //to give alternate background fill color to rows// 
            $fill=false;
            foreach ($data as $row) {
                $pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],10,$row['sl_no'],1,0,C,$fill);
                $pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],10,$row['owner_name'],1,0,L,$fill);
                $pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],10,$row['last_update'],1,0,C,$fill);
                $pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],10,$row['book_id'],1,0,C,$fill);
                $pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,$row['operator_total'],1,1,C,$fill);
                $pdf->Cell($width_cell[5],10,$row['ride_total'],1,1,C,$fill);
                $fill = !$fill;
            }
            $today = date('YmdHi');
            $filename='report_'.$today.'.pdf';
            $totalpath='/var/www/hlwcab.com/public_html/cab/service/admin/report/download/'.$filename;
            $pdf->Output($totalpath, "F");
            $result1["msg"] = "Succesfully Downloaded...";
        }else{
            header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
            $result1["msg"] = "No record to download...";
        }
        //print_r($result1);exit;
        echo json_encode($result1);
    }
```

Here I am first fetching the data from `MySQL` table and creating the pdf file which is given below.

[image]

Here the last header column is breaking and coming to down. Here I need to set all header part of column in the same row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the 2nd one (1) in the line below to zero (0).

From:

```
pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,'Operator',1,1,C,true);
```

To:

```
pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,'Operator',1,0,C,true);
```

Do the same for the cell in the loop that outputs the actual values. From:

```
pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,$row['operator_total'],1,1,C,$fill);
```

To:

```
pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,$row['operator_total'],1,0,C,$fill);
```